# Lebesgue integration - Royden 4.4 #36

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am working on Royden's Real Analysis 4th edition, Chapter 4.4, #36.

Please let me know how I should go forth:

**Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function defined on a square $Q=\{(x, y) | 0 \leq x, y \leq 1\}$ and is a measurable function of $x$ for each fixed value of $y$. For each point $(x, y) \in Q$ let $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist. If there is a function $g$ integrable over $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack$ such that $\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, y) \vert \leq g(x)$ for all $(x, y) \in Q$, 
show that $\frac{d}{dt}\lbrack \int_0^{1} f(x, y) \,dx \rbrack = \int_0^{1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) dx$ for all $y \in \lbrack 0, 1\rbrack$.**

Thank you very much!

Comment: For one thing, I am unable to see how the derivative being bounded above by $g$ fits into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof, leaving you a few details to fill in.

The function $x \to f(x,y)$ is integrable for each $y$.

Consider a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n \to y.$

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is  some $\xi$
 between $y_n$ and $y$ such that 
$$\left| \frac{f(x,y_n) -f(x,y)}{y_n-y} \right| = \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi) \right| \leqslant g(x).$$

Now apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to

$$\frac{F(y_n)-F(y)}{y_n -y}= \int_0^1 \frac{f(x,y_n)-f(x,y)}{y_n-y} \, dx,$$

where

$$F(y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dx.$$

Comment: Maybe it is too late to ask, but how do we know that the function $x\longrightarrow f(x,y)$ is integrable for each $y$? It is just given that it is measurable on the interval $[0,1]$? Which condition does guarantee that it is integrable ?

Comment: If the function $x\longrightarrow f(x,y)$ is bounded on the interval $[0,1]$ (for each $y$), then it must be integrable, but I do not know how to show that it is bounded on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @serenus:  Boundedness would be sufficient, but that is not stated explicitly above.  However, if $f(x,y_0)$ is integrable for at least one point $y_0$ then $f(x,y)$ is integrable for every $y \in [0,1]$. By the MVT there exists $\xi$ such that $f(x,y) - f(x,y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi)$ and $|f(x,y)| \leqslant |f(x,y_0)| + \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi)  \right| \leqslant |f(x,y_0)| + g(x)$ where the RHS is integrable.

Comment: But, is there really such a point $y_0\in [0,1]$? Or, should we assume the existence of such a point $y_0$ as an additional hypothesis? I understand that we should assume the integrability of $f(., y_0)$ (for some $y_0$ in $[0,1]$) as a hypothesis in the statement of the problem. Am I right?

Comment: @serenus:  Yes the question is not well-written.  The minimal additional assumption needed is integrability for one point $y_0$ followed by my proof in the comment. Otherwise if $f(x,y)$ is not integrable for every $y$, then there is not much point to the question.